# How to modify PHP user/password script to only require password

Tags: php, password-protection

I have searched for weeks, but cannot find anything relevant to this specific problem.

I have a PHP page of live.php. It successfully requires a user name and password to access a protected page (livedata.php). The following form is in live.php:

```
<form name="LoginForm" form action="liveverify.php" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
Password:<input type="password" name="password" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
```

liveverify.php has:

```
<?php
$usernames = array("user1, uer2, user3");
$passwords = array("pass1, pass2, pass3");
$page = "livedata.php";

for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++) 
{  
$logindata[$usernames[$i]]=$passwords[$i];
}
$found = 0; for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++) {    if ($usernames[$i] == $_POST["username"])        {    $found = 1;    } } if ($found == 0) {    header('Location: liveerror.php');    exit; }
if($logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]){   session_start();   $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];   header('Location: '.$page);   exit;}else{   header('Location: liveerror.php');   exit;}?>
```

My desire is to eliminate the need for a user name, and only require a valid password. I assume I need to eliminate references to the user name in liveverify.php. However, everything I have tried has failed. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Well... yes, you just have to eliminate al references to usernames...

Comment: How are the passwords really stored?

Comment: Answered below. Small website, nothing of value, just tryingto keep out general public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems a little strange to ignore the username, but assuming that username will still be passed via the form you should be able to do something like

```
$passwords = array( "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" );
$page = "livedata.php";

if ( in_array($_POST["password"], $passwords) )
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[ "username" ] = $_POST[ "username" ];
    header( 'Location: ' . $page );
    exit;
}
else
{
    header( 'Location: liveerror.php' );
    exit;
}
```

This will allow username to not match and become anything user likes though

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It is a very small website just looking to keep out the general public. Nothing of value. thanks